# How to add the previous field plus the next in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have three tables:

- The "record" table has a date field called "date_record", a foreign key of a "customer" table together with a foreign key of a "reward" table and its respective primary key
- The "reward" table has three fields: its primary key, a column that stores integer values called "reward_value" and a description
- The "client" table has two fields: its primary key and the client's
  name

What I want is simply to sum the integer values (fields "reward_value", like a Fibonacci series), but showing the date fields and taking into account the customer ID, I know that programming is quite easy, but so far I got to give a query (if possible) that allows to do all this from the database engine

Query:

```
SELECT record.date_record, reward.reward_value
FROM record, reward, client
WHERE client.id = record.id
AND   reward.id = record.id
AND client.id = 0;
```

Output:

```
|date_record  | reward_value  | 
+-------------+---------------+
| 2017-01-10  | 30            | 
| 2017-01-10  | 10            | 
| 2017-03-18  | 25            |
| 2017-05-11  | 35            |
```

What I want:

```
|date_record  | reward_value  | 
+-------------+---------------+
| 2017-01-10  | 30            | (30 + 0)
| 2017-01-10  | 40            | (30 + 10)
| 2017-03-18  | 65            | (40 + 25)
| 2017-05-11  | 100           | (65 + 35)
```

Comment: This is a running total. It has been solved dozens and dozens of times. The exact solution will depend on which version of sql server you are using. The biggest issue I see is that you need something to define the order of your table and from the data posted date_record is close but also not good enough as you have duplicates.

Comment: I use SQL Server 2014, I also thought of duplicate records, that is to say that equal dates are registered but in that case it would be convenient to add the duplicate values and "convert it into a field", then apply the logic that I propose

Comment: So which one came "first"? reward_value 30 or 40? And how do you know? By definition a table is an unordered set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sql server 2012 onward you can use windowed functions:

```
SELECT     date_Record
,          sum(reward_value) OVER(ORDER BY date_record) reward_value
FROM       Your_Table
```

However, as Sean Lange rightly commented, you need a unique value to `order by`, otherwise the results are not going to be consistent. Since you have duplicates in the date range, you need to add or replace with a unique column.

Comment: Great answer but you can't do this until sql 2012. :)

Comment: It works correctly, but instead of DESC it is ASC in my case